# quiz in tkinter, Index out of range

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a project, that currently will only ask 1 question and then break, giving me the message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the error is on line 42 which is:

```
label.config(text=question[q]).
```

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

q = -1
count = 0
correct = 0
incorrect = 0

question=["File compression software is an example of.. software", "Each piece of hardware e.g printer, monitor, keyboard, will need an up to date... installed", "application softwares control the computer, true or false?"]
answer = ["utility", "driver", "false"]
answer_cap = ["Utility","Driver","False"]
root = Tk()

name = tk.Label(root,text = "Computing quiz")
name.pack()

label = tk.Label(root,text = question[0])
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack() 

def out():
    global q,correct,incorrect,count
    while count < len(question):
          ans = entry.get()
          if answer[q] == ans or answer_cap[q] == ans :
              q+=1
              entry.delete(0, END)
              correct+=1
              print(correct)
              label.config(text=question[q])
          else:
              q+=1
              entry.delete(0, END)
              incorrect+=1
              print(incorrect)
              label.config(text=question[q])

    entry.delete(0, END)
    label.config(text = "Correct: "+str(correct) + " Incorrect:   "+str(incorrect))

    print(correct)

def stop():
    global q,correct,incorrect
    q = 0
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    entry.delete(0, END)
    label.config(text = question[0])

button = tk.Button(root,text = "Submit",command = out)
button.pack()

button_two = tk.Button(root,text = "Restart",command = stop)
button_two.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at your `while` loop. You are doing something `while count < ...`, but inside the loop `count` is not updated, but `q` is. Because of this `q` will be very very big soon, so it will be much higher then the `len(question)`. No wonder the `IndexError`

You have to correct that loop, because even if you deal with the `IndexError` the `while` loop will run forever.

A workaround (I do not suggest this, in my opinion you should just correct the whole `while` loop) could be to `except` the `IndexError` and `break` out of the loop

Comment: label.config(text=question[q]) still has an index error.

Comment: Still gives error is not a surprise. Think about how large your list is, and how big `q` is. If q is bigger then the length of your list, it will give you an `IndexError`.  I would suggest to use a `for` loop instead of the `while len(list)` stuff.